# buildSrc folder to organize an Android/Kotlin project dependencies/metadata

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Following Google's recommendation of using extra properties to share them through your project, I came across a nice solution based on buildSrc + Kotlin gradle script for my Android/Kotlin projects. This solution provides me very nice advantages comparing to the other classic approach of having multiple Groovy written `build.gradle` files per module (plus the root one) with their dependencies, parameters. The main ones are:

- Using kotlin syntax.
- Compilation errors.
- Auto-completion.
- Click support (navigate to definition)
- Centralize gradle files metadata information in one file.

Check [this article](https://handstandsam.com/2018/02/11/kotlin-buildsrc-for-better-gradle-dependency-management/) for more information.

If I'm not wrong, Kotlin-dsl team members recommend to use IntelliJ for it, and the integration with Android Studio doesn't seem to be fully completed, since I still see some Kotlin gradle script code highlighted in red. However, it compiles well. Weird thing is if I clone for example the [Prefekt repository](https://github.com/StylingAndroid/Prefekt/tree/master/buildSrc) I'm able to see the `build.gradle.kts` content perfectly without red marks after a gradle sync. I've almost done everything (sync gradle, invalidate cache, remove cache, same gradle wrapper, etc) in my project to vanish those marks without any success. Here are some side questions:

1. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to remove those red marks?
2. Although I like this approach, one thing I'll miss a lot is the outdated dependency check highlight in the gradle file which suggests there's a new x.y.x version of the library. Is there any way to get it work with this approach?
3. Is there any way to use [gradle project properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#N14A8D) from within the buildSrc Kotlin classes? for example it's very common to work with property files (e.g *version.properties*) and gradle properties like `rootDir` are very helpful to get their path. We could use `Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()` for that purpose, but it's not a clean solution.
4. What do you generally think about this approach?